# Displaying the value of the EditText in the TextView at the Simultaneous(online) in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, textview, android-edittext

I want the text written inside the EditText to be displayed simultaneously in the TextView without pressing the button
(kotlin)

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `TextWatcher` and in `afterTextChanged` update the `TextView`

```
editText.addextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher {
    ...
    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        s?.let { textView.text = it.toString() }
    }
})
```

Or if you're using the `androidx.core:core-ktx` library:

```
editText.doAfterTextChanged { editable ->
    editable?.let { textView.text = it.toString()
}
```